# Combinatory Logic Problem With Partial Reductions

Tags: logic, type-theory, lambda-calculus, higher-order-logic, combinatory-logic

I'm working through Bacon's Philosophical Introduction to Higher Order Logic. I am looking for help on the following problem:

> **Exercise 3.17** Calculate the following, assuming that $\wedge : t \to t \to t, F : e \to t \in \Sigma.:$

Rather than translating into combinatory logic without variables, these exercises include arbitrary variables. Basically, I'm meant to be calculating terms of $CL^v(\{S,K,I\},\Sigma)$

(The only things needed to solve this problem are $S, K, I$, constants, and the arbitary variables).

---

so, the first problem is

1. $[x].Sxy$ where $x : t \to t \to t, y : t \to t$, and $S: (t\to t \to t) \to (t \to t) \to t \to t$

If I understand the combinators correctly,

$
\begin{align*}
[x].Sxy  &= S([x].x)([x].y) \\
&= \boxed{S(I)(Ky)}
\end{align*}
$

Is this right? I'm honestly pretty confused. And it gets worse :(

2. $[x].Fx$, where $F : e \to t$ is a constant and $x : e$

In this case since F is a constant, which makes me confused, are you supposed to do:

$
\begin{align*}
[x].Fx  &= S([x].F)([x].x) \\
&= \boxed{S(KF)(I)}
\end{align*}
$
??

This seems right to me, since $[x]PQ = S([x].P)([x].Q)$, but, am I right in assuming that for a constant $F$, $[x].F = KF$?? I feel like it has to be since $F : e \to t \in \Sigma$.

3. $[x].(Fx \wedge Gx)$

At this point I'm losing my marbles... (also, for this problem I will format my solution with prefix notation after setting up the problem).

$
\begin{align*}
[x].(Fx \wedge Gx) &= S([x].\wedge Fx)([x].Gx) \\
&= S(S([x].\wedge)([x].Fx))(S([x].G)([x].x)) \\
&= S(S([x].\wedge)(S([x].F)([x].x)))(S([x].G)([x].x)) \\
&= \boxed{S(S(\wedge)(S(KF)(I)))(S(KG)(I))} 
\end{align*}
$

My solution to that one is really dependent on my understanding what is happening in (2). Unfortunately, I do not know from where to start (4) without first understanding that I've done 1-3 correctly, but I'll include it here:

4. $[x].SK$, choosing appropriate type subscripts.

Any advice or hints would be massively appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These answers look good to me. In the final line of Q3 it looks like you missed a $K$ (you should have $K\wedge$ where you have $\wedge$).

For 4 I won't do the type superscripts. We have $[x].SK$ then $S([x].S)([x].K)$, and then $S(KS)(KK)$.